# Parsing XML to CSV while combining some fields values into one field with commas

Tags: php

i have products.xml file, and i want to make it csv, but with combining image1, image2 and etc to one csv column field, links to be separeted by commas.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
  <product>
    <product_id>14</product_id>
    <name><![CDATA[Tricycle Vetta Melange Beige]]></name>
    <date_created><![CDATA[2018-09-11 13:07:14]]></date_created>
    <sku><![CDATA[31006020047]]></sku>
    <product_url><![CDATA[https://localhost/trikolka-vetta-melange-beige]]></product_url>
    <stock_status>In Stock</stock_status>
    <parent_cat><![CDATA[All (Test)]]></parent_cat>
    <sub_cat><![CDATA[Tricycles]]></sub_cat>
    <description><![CDATA[Tricycle 3 in 1
(max. weigh load – 30 kg).
]]></description>
    <description_html><![CDATA[Tricycle 3 in 1
(max. weigh load – 30 kg).
]]></description_html>
    <characteristics>
      <weight>15.6000</weight>
      <volume>0.130</volume>
      <barcode>3801006020477</barcode>
    </characteristics>
    <images>
      <image_1>img_1593.jpg</image_1>
      <image_2>vetta_beige_side_1.jpg</image_2>
      <image_3>beige2.jpg</image_3>
      <image_4>beige_up.jpg</image_4>
      <image_5>beige_bike_1.jpg</image_5>
    </images>
  </product>
```

CSV should be with headers, and all images links in  to be in one field in the csv, separeted with commas

```
img_1593.jpg,vetta_beige_side_1.jpg,beige2.jpg etc.
```

product_id,

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What doesn't work with the code you've written so far?

Comment: I cant make the code working to conbine me all pics links in one filed. My code make it to be to separete columns in csv, not in one image column, and the links separed with commas

Comment: Just put quotes around the image field, else the CSV parser will think they're all separate fields. (Or use something besides a comma to separate the images.)

Comment: Change this:
img_1593.jpg,vetta_beige_side_1.jpg,beige2.jpg
to this:
"img_1593.jpg,vetta_beige_side_1.jpg",beige2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

How are you parsing this XML?

If you re doing it yourself in php (as you tagged this question) then I would make a class called 'product' which constructs using each product node, adding each subnode as a single property or array, and then add a 'asCSVRow()' function which returns a string. You can then do anything you want with the properties regardless of how the XML structured them.

eg

```
class product { 

    /*------*/
    function __construct($productNode) {
        $this->name = $productNode->name;
        //Add other properties here
        $this->images = array();
        foreach ($productNode->images as $imageNode) {
          $this->images[] = $imageNode;
        }
        //Syntax of this will differ depending on your method of parsing
    }

    /*------*/
    public asCSVRow(){
        return sprintf(
            '"%s","%s"' . PHP_EOL,
            $this->name,
            implode(',', $this->images)
        );
        //Add other properties, and protect against double quotes in strings.
    }

    /*------*/
}
```

**Note** - This is only sudo-code and is not copy and pastable, it just shows that regardless of the language used, manual parsing/handling can return you what ever you want